# Comando django-admin startproject não cria o arquivo manage.py

Tags: django, django-admin

1. Após rodar o comando django-admin startproject o arquivo manage.py não é criado.
2. Estou usando o python 2.7.12
3. testei com as versões do django-1.4.3 e django 1.5.1.

Comment: E quais são os arquivos criados? Por favor, edite a pergunta e adicione a lista dos mesmos. Aliás, por quê não aproveita e faz o [tour] pelo site? Pode ser interessante aprender o básico de como o site funciona.

Comment: São criados apenas os arquivos 
-__init__.py
-settings.py
-urls.py
-wsgi.py

Comment: E no diretório acima?

Comment: O primeiro diretório fica apenas com um subdiretório com o mesmo nome.

Comment: diga todos os arquivos que tem nesse diretorio e mande o caminho deles pra gente, provavel que o manage.py esteja no diretorio acima e vc nao viu

Comment: Ao aplicar o comando django-admin startproject MeuSite os arquivos criados são os seguintes: 1.MeuSite - 1.1MeuSite 1.1.1__init__.py 1.1.2__settings.py 1.1.3__urls.py 1.1.4 wsgi.py

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse bug aqui: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19958 De acordo com ele, pode ser que você tenha uma instalação do Django duplicada e corrompida que não tenha o `manage.py`. Se você apagar a corrompida, pode ser que resolva seu problema.

Comment: Por outros motivos formatei meu PC, instalei o python2.7 novamente e o virtualenv e estou usando a configuração no-site-package no virtualenv, não tenho nenhuma instalação do django no diretório do python em C:\Python27 apenas no ambiente virtual. Verifiquei que exite o arquivo manage.py no diretório django\conf\project_template, porém ao executar o comando startproject ele continua não criando. Para outras versões do python e do django o manage.py é criado, por exemplo quando uso o python 3.5 com o django 1.11.3 ele funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se foi o caso mas tente colocar o nome do diretório no final, exemplo:

Você colocou `django-admin startproject`
tente colocar `django-admin startproject nome_da_pasta`

sei que sua pergunta é antiga mas deve ajudar alguém